# Date no greater than the current year or next year

Tags: date, ms-access

I need to set a validation rule in Access so that the DateOfArrival is always after the DateOfTheOrder.
I also have to make sure that the DateOfArrival is not set too far away in the future...so it shouldn't be greater than the current year or the following at max (for cases such: order 31 dec 2015, arrival 1 jan 2016).

I've put:

```
[DateOfArrival]>[DateofOrder] AND [DateOfArrival]<=Year(Date())+1
```

in the validation rules but if I enter DateofOrder=31/12/2015 and DateOfArrival=01/01/2016 it gives me an error. Can you help me?
The error must be in the second part of the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dateOfArrival] is a Date, while YEAR(Date()) is an Integer ...

When comparing them, [dateOfArrival] will be considered as a number, being the number of days since the 31/12/1899, and YEAR(date()) will be definitely and always lower than this number.

You should compare YEAR(dateOfArrival) with YEAR(date()))!